# Setting values in 2D Arrays

Tags: arrays, ocaml

When trying to set a value in a 2D array like this:

```
let a = Array.make  5 (Array.make 5 0);;
a.(0).(0) <- 4;
```

It will for some reason put `4` at index `j` in every array contained in the 2D array `a`.

Why is this, and how do i get it to only set `a[i][j]` to `4`?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is with how you initialize the matrix. You're creating one inner array that is then assigned to every cell of the outer array instead of creating a new array for each cell. What you're doing is equivalent to this:

```
let inner = Array.make 5 0 in
let outer = Array.make 5 inner in
inner.(0) <- 4
```

You could use `Array.init` to create the outer array instead, which behaves exactly like `Array.make` except it takes an initialization function instead of the value to insert directly:

```
Array.init 5 (fun _ -> Array.make 5 0)
```

But even more convenient for creating a 2-dimensional array is `Array.make_matrix`:

```
Array.make_matrix 5 5 0;;
```

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to [glennsl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74329073/15261315), you will see this issue anytime you store a *mutable* value in an array.

Consider:

```
let arr =
  let x = ref 5 in
  Array.make 5 x
```

If we assign a new value to that `int ref` value with `arr.(1) := 7` or `arr.(0).contents <- 7`, `arr` is now:

```
[|{contents = 7}; {contents = 7}; {contents = 7}; 
  {contents = 7}; {contents = 7}|]
```

The same does not apply if we fill our array with immutable data.

```
let arr = 
  let x = 5 in
  Array.make 5 x
```

Now if we update with `arr.(0) <- 7`, `arr` is:

```
[|7; 5; 5; 5; 5|]
```